# Chrome app start tcp server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I tried to start a simple tcp-server:

```
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({}, function(info){
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(info.socketId, 'localhost', 2000, function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

But somehow `console.log(result);` always prints out `undefined`!

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer#method-create

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer#method-listen

What do i wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does it succeed? Can you see a port being opened to listen? (use netstat on Linux or on Mac)

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà thanks for this hint i will test it tommorrow and lets see what happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the following permission to your manifest :

```
"sockets": {
  "tcpServer" : {
    "listen": ["host-pattern1", ...],
    ...
  }
}
```

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network